# How to fix "getMonth" showing next year's month too

Tags: javascript, date, gantt-chart

my problem is that the months are displaying till "April" which means starting from Jan to Next Year's April. I only need to display months till December.

This is my JavaScript code

```js
var vals = [date.getFullYear() + (scale === YEAR ? qty : 0),
  date.getMonth() + (scale === MONTH ? qty : 0),
  date.getDate() + (scale === DAY ? qty : 0),
  date.getHours() + (scale === HOUR ? qty : 0),
  date.getMinutes() + (scale === MINUTE ? qty : 0),
  date.getSeconds() + (scale === SECOND ? qty : 0),
  date.getMilliseconds() + (scale === MILLISECOND ? qty : 0)
];
    return new Date(...vals);
},

start_of(date, scale) {
    const scores = {
        [YEAR]: 6,
        [MONTH]: 5,
        [DAY]: 4,
        [HOUR]: 3,
        [MINUTE]: 2,
        [SECOND]: 1,
        [MILLISECOND]: 0
    };

    function should_reset(_scale) {
        const max_score = scores[scale];
        return scores[_scale] <= max_score;
    }

    const vals = [
        date.getFullYear(),
        should_reset(YEAR) ? 0 : date.getMonth(),
        should_reset(MONTH) ? 1 : date.getDate(),
        should_reset(DAY) ? 0 : date.getHours(),
        should_reset(HOUR) ? 0 : date.getMinutes(),
        should_reset(MINUTE) ? 0 : date.getSeconds(),
        should_reset(SECOND) ? 0 : date.getMilliseconds()
    ];

    return new Date(...vals);
},
```

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        var gantt_data = <?php echo json_encode($gantt_data); ?>;

        if (gantt_data.length > 0) {
            var gantt = new Gantt("#gantt", gantt_data, {
                view_modes: ['Day', 'Week', 'Month', 'Year'],
                view_mode: 'Month',
                date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                column_width: 30,

            });

            $("#gantt g.handle-group").hide();

            $('body').on('mouseleave', '.grid-row', function() {
                gantt.hide_popup();
            })

            $('select[name$="gantt_view"').change(function(el) {
                let view = $(el.target).val();
                gantt.change_view_mode(view);
            });
        }

    })
</script>
```

I am not sure if something else could be causing this problem. I'm using Gantt chart and I only want to display 12 months.

I'm using this gantt.
https://github.com/frappe/gantt

Comment: I made a snippet. Please update it to a [mcve] - it is not clear at all what your code is doing

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, I have added the whole script link which I'm using. I'm sorry I'm just kinda new here.

Comment: @ShirleyEng Please add the relevant code to the question itself as a [mcve]. [We don't allow code hidden behind links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/479156). And if you're new, please see [ask].

Comment: @Ivar Thanks for the guide, I've updated it. I have referenced the script so people know what I'm using and doing.

Comment: Please ADD HTML and RELEVANT SCRIPT in the panes of the snippet. Click [edit], scroll down, click "Edit above snippet" and add all script in the bottom left and choose relevant libraries and add the others from CDNs if needed. I already spent time and will not spend more time to make a [mcve] <<<-- Please read this link

Comment: @mplungjan Instead of format, if you would focus on the problem it would be more helpful btw, you are teaching me how to set formats while I don't think it's even a big issue, I'm here to ask for help to fix the problem and all you guys are doing is telling me how to fix format.

Comment: Instead of us having to eyeball-debug your code, you could post what we expect to debug so we can concentrate on the problem and not try to guess what the code does

Comment: So we REPEAT: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: @mplungjan I clearly mentioned what it does and included the relevant javascript code,  script, and chart function. I'm using it's date_utils function and even I don't understand why is the script showing me months till April while it should just show me till December. The whole js is very big and if something else could be causing the problem I would be greatful if you can guide or help me in any way.

Comment: You have var vals and const vals - that might give an issue

Comment: If this is the script, you could ask there: https://github.com/frappe/gantt/issues

Comment: @mplungjan I checked there It's no use, nobody is getting their problems solved there or even getting response and I really need to fix it fast or find a solution.

Comment: I am sorry, without running code and no example of the gantt data, I personally cannot help you

Comment: The posted code is incomplete, contains syntax errors, contains PHP code that is essential to understand the functions. The question infers a loop, yet there is no loop in the posted code, it doesn't seem to have any relevance to the code. You need at least minimal input with expected and actual output or results.